# Unbuntu 20 KVM forces Console mode out of range tried GFXMODE

Tags: display-resolution, kvm-virtualization

Console only no "desktop" I installed 20.04 with a monitor directly attached to it, no problems. Console only no "desktop". I've put it at the end of a KVM, and the monitor's coming up out of range. Through ssh I've tried setting GFXMODE in /etc/default/grub and update-grub, then a reboot. If I leave the the KVM while booting, both the KVM's monitor and directly attached monitor are "out of range" if I plug in the monitor directly without a KVM, the monitor works fine.

I need to set the resolution to something like 1024*768 ad possibly a slower refresh rate, but I can't work out how.

The KVM are 5-ish years old, I suspect they are the source of the problem, but they can't be replaced. so I just need to lower the resolution.

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Answer for anyone else having the problem :-)

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-increase-tty-console-resolution-on-ubuntu-18-04-server